# Dynamically changing the design of pivot item in Pivot control

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, uwp

I am using pivot control in Windows phone 8.1 UWP,I need to binding data dynamically to pivot header and pivot item template.

I need the first pivot item with one design and for other pivot header and items i need other design template i.e., for example, for the first pivot item i need an image only and for other items i want a list view which includes image and text block.

Please help me how to do this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ItemTemplateSelector. In the Pivot element lookout for HeaderTemplate property. Construct your Itemtemplateselector and use that to change the header of the pivot.

Comment: Hi Chirag. Can you please explain this issue using some sample code